# how do i get array element isMultiple in php

Tags: php, arrays

hi there i am new to php  and  i want to access **isMultiple** element of array how can i do that then i want to show if the value of **isMultiple** is 1 then it should show **yes**..  any help would be appreciated and it would be great......!!.

```
Array
(

    [result] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [pkFeatureTypeId] => 72
                    [Name] => 
                    [Status] => 0
                    [isMultiple] => 1
                    [isSpecial] => 1
                    [Order] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [pkFeatureTypeId] => 32
                    [Name] => 
                    [Status] => 0
                    [isMultiple] => 1
                    [isSpecial] => 1
                    [Order] => 0
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [pkFeatureTypeId] => 33
                    [Name] => 
                    [Status] => 0
                    [isMultiple] => 1
                    [isSpecial] => 1
                    [Order] => 0
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [pkFeatureTypeId] => 35
                    [Name] => 
                    [Status] => 1
                    [isMultiple] => 1
                    [isSpecial] => 1
                    [Order] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Its very easy with foreach, Have you tried yourself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
foreach($data['result'] as $item){
   if($item['isMultiple'] == '1'){
      echo 'Yes';
   }
}
```

Comment: thanx v much let me try